# Disallow Image Loading to Reduce Number of "Other Error" in Crawled Page Resources?

Tags: googlebot, images, ajax, crawl-errors, crawl-budget

We have a hotel search website. Many landing pages of our site load resources asynchrously (e.g. Ajax), but very often (about 25% of the time) when we click "View Crawled Page" in Google Search Console URL Inspection, we can see that certain important API calls on the pages are not loaded, and they are showing "Other Error". This includes API calls to show relevant reviews, which shows our unique value for travelers. We have more than 100K such pages.

[image: URL Inspection 'More Info' Tab]

We have read similar posts such as this one (https://support.google.com/webmasters/thread/4425254?hl=en) about "Other error" in page resources that are not loaded, and it looks like there is unique resource quota (i.e. limited number of requests Googlebot would like to perform) determined Googlebot for each website. Specifically for our case, we have seen different resources being blocked. They are:

1. Important API calls mentioned above;
2. Hotel images
3. Google Analytics /collect (shown as image requests in Google search console)

**My questions are:**

1. Does it harm SEO when I block Hotel images in robots.txt to reduce other errors in API calls?
2. Is there a way to block Google Analytics in Google Analytics settings when the useragent is Googlebot?